# second order linear differential equation: inhomogeneous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following equation to solve for $y$:

$$my'' + ny' = 2kT$$
Where $m, n, k, T$ are positive constants and $y=y(x)$. Also, $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$.

Firstly, is this a non homogeneous equation? If so, for my particular solution, should I choose my "guess" solution form to be a polynomial? would it be a constant in this case?

Comment: yep, sure sorry!

Comment: EDIT! It is kT and in a physical context! sorry my fault

Answer (score 0):

Considering the equation $$m y''+n y'=2k T$$ you could first reduce the order using $z=y'$. This makes the equation to become $$m z'+n z=2kT$$ The solution of the homogeneous equation is just $$z=C e^{-\frac{n }{m}T}$$ Using the variation of parameters then leads to $$m C' e^{-\frac{n }{m}T}=2kT\implies C'=\frac{2 k T e^{\frac{n }{m}T}}{m}$$ and integration by parts would lead to $$C=\frac{2 k e^{\frac{n T}{m}} (n T-m)}{n^2}+D$$ that is to say $$z=D e^{-\frac{n }{m}T}-\frac{2 k m}{n^2}+\frac{2 k T}{n}$$ Now, the condition $y'(0)=0$ implies $z(0)=0$ that is to say $$D=\frac{2 k m}{n^2}$$ $$z=\frac{2 k m e^{-\frac{n T}{m}}}{n^2}-\frac{2 k m}{n^2}+\frac{2 k T}{n}$$ All of that makes $$y'=\frac{2 k m }{n^2}e^{-\frac{n }{m}T}-\frac{2 k m}{n^2}+\frac{2 k T}{n}$$ which is easy to integrate. At the end, impose the condition $y(0)=0$ to get the solution.